# DataGridViewColumn HeaderText did not show and disappear when columns are added dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

Code:

```
private void Do_FillGrid() {
    DataGridViewColumnCollection Cols = new DataGridViewColumnCollection(Data_Grid1);
    Data_Grid1.ColumnCount = 5;
    Data_Grid1.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
    try
    {
        Cols.Add("Col_xID", "p_ID");
        Cols.Add("Col_Unit", "p_Unit");
        Cols.Add("Col_Date", "p_Date");

        Cols.Add("Col_ValStr", "p_Value");
        Cols.Add("Col_Status", "p_Status");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    foreach (SimpleEdnaTag oneTag in MyTags)
    {
        Data_Grid1.Rows.Add(
            oneTag._id, oneTag._Units, oneTag._PointDate, oneTag._PointValueString, oneTag._PointStatus);
    }
}
```

[image: Missing HeaderText on my Columns]

Is there any reason or anything I did above that my Column Header cannot show up ?

Comment: In your code the command that added columns to the grid is: `Data_Grid1.ColumnCount = 5;` and your code which is in a try/catch block only generates an exception and will not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would use DatagridViewColumnCollection.

Try this maybe.

```
            Data_Grid1.Columns.Add("Col_xID", "p_ID");
            ...
```

Comment: KonB, thks, the better way to do it is to store the pointer to the collection in a variable.  See my answer below when i tried to simplify yours.

Comment: Not a problem, just writing with what I had. A most likely scenario for me would be something like Reza wrote, on the bottom. Create an external structure, a list, or something else, and bind it dynamically to the datagrid through datasource.

Comment: Thanks, I have a new posted answer like you said. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way of adding column to grid. In your code the command that added columns to the grid is: `Data_Grid1.ColumnCount = 5;` and your code which is in a `try/catch` block only generates an exception and will not execute.

To add columns to grid, you can use:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("columnName", "headerText")
```

Also you should know you can set a list as `DataSource` of the grid:

```
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource= myList;
```

This way you don't need to add rows or columns one by one.

Comment: thx again guys. The reason I can't use Data_Grid1.DataSource = MyTags is that I only need a few fields from MyTags, not all. Don't know any quick way to get around that.

Comment: Sorry Reza, I was wrong. I can do it, I use Linq.  See my last posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting ColumnHeadersVisible = true on your control in your InitializeComponent method/designer code?

```
Data_Grid1.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
```

If this doesn't work, try refreshing the control once you've your rows AND the ColumnHeadersVisible property is set to true.

```
Data_Grid1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Colums Header this way:

```
Data_Grid1.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
Data_Grid1.ColumnCount = 5;

Data_Grid1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "p_ID";
Data_Grid1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "p_Unit";
Data_Grid1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "p_Date";
Data_Grid1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "p_Value";
Data_Grid1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "p_Status";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou guys. I have re-arranged my code a little bit. It's fine now -->

```
private void Do_FillGrid() {
    DataGridViewColumnCollection theCols = Data_Grid1.Columns;
    try
    {
        theCols.Add("Col_xID", "p_ID");
        theCols.Add("Col_Unit", "p_Unit");
        theCols.Add("Col_Date", "p_Date");
        theCols.Add("Col_ValStr", "p_ValStr");
        theCols.Add("Col_Status", "p_Status");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    foreach (SimpleEdnaTag oneTag in MyTags) {
        Data_Grid1.Rows.Add(
            oneTag._id, oneTag._Units, oneTag._PointDate, oneTag._PointValueString, oneTag._PointStatus);
    }
}
```

[image: header OK]

Answer (score 0):

outThx again Kon. Using Reza's like you said, I apply Linq to select fields to output.

```
using System.Linq;
private void Do_FillGrid() {
    var objSelectedFields = myTags.Select(tag => new { id = tag._id, unit = tag._unit, date = tag._date, val = tag._valStr, stat = tag._status }).ToList();
    this.Data_Grid1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    this.Data_Grid1.DataSource = objSelectedFields;
}
```

[image: header OK2]